# Are there any good general techniques for binning/histogramming arbitrary data?

Tags: data-mining, visualization

Let's say we want to histogram a finite set of measurements of some quantity. It is straight forward to calculate the usual statistical quantities for our sample such as the mean and the variance. Let's assume we can clean up our data by identifying outliers and moving them into underflow and overflow bins and thus, define more or less optimal min and max values for the plotting range. But how would one decide on the number and the size of bins? I would like to know if there are methods to find the optimal binning for the cases with fixed and variable bin sizes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a stats question answered here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/calculating-optimal-number-of-bins-in-a-histogram

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this what you want but here is a way to calculate the number of bins.

1. Count the number of data points in your dataset.
2. Take the square root of the number of data points and round up to determine the initial number of bins required: $InitialNumberOfBins = \sqrt{NumberOfDataPoints}$.
3. Divide the specification tolerance $Max-Min\ value$ by initial number of bins: $FinalNumberOfBins = (Max-Min\ value) / InitialNumberOfBins$.

Comment: (1 - 0) / sqrt(10000) = 0.01 bins?? How does that work?

Comment: you square root the number of data points i.e (√144)= 12 initial bins

Comment: Yes, 10k data points, normalized to [0, 1], squared, as above. Gives 0.01 bins.

Comment: I don't remember saying to normalize the data.

Comment: Sorry, it was already normalized. But I just used it as an example. The real data has values between 14.03 and 14.93, roughly normally distributed. So?

Comment: Where do these rules come from and what do they accomplish?